# Drawing thousands of polygons with OpenGL VBO

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, 2d, vbo

I'm trying to create OpenGL application capable of rendering over 100000 2d primitive objects.

AFAIK, it should be possible using modern OpenGL and VBO.

So here is the code (uses Qt):

```
#include "paintwidget.h"

PaintWidget::PaintWidget(QGLWidget *parent) : QGLWidget(parent)
{
    QTimer *timer = new QTimer(this);
    connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(updateTimer()));
    timer->start(16);
}

GLuint indices[100000];

void PaintWidget::initializeGL()
{
    VBOBuffer= new QGLBuffer(QGLBuffer::VertexBuffer);
    VBOBuffer->create();
    VBOBuffer->bind();
    VBOBuffer->setUsagePattern(QGLBuffer::DynamicDraw);
    VBOBuffer->allocate(100000 * 10 * sizeof(double));

    // load data into VBO:
    for(int i=0; i<100000; i++)
    {

        GLdouble vertices[] = {100 + (double)i * 100, 100 + (double)i * 100,
                               100 + (double)i * 100, 200 + (double)i * 100,
                               200 + (double)i * 100, 200 + (double)i * 100,
                               300 + (double)i * 100, 150 + (double)i * 100,
                               200 + (double)i * 100, 100 + (double)i * 100 };

        VBOBuffer->write(i * 10 * sizeof(double), vertices, 10 * sizeof(double));
    }

    // fill indices array:
    for(int i=0; i<100000; i+=10)
    {
        indices[i] = i;
        indices[i+1] = i+1;
        indices[i+2] = i+1;
        indices[i+3] = i+2;
        indices[i+4] = i+2;
        indices[i+5] = i+3;
        indices[i+6] = i+3;
        indices[i+7] = i+4;
        indices[i+8] = i+4;
        indices[i+9] = i;
    }
}

void PaintWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent*)
{
    QPainter paint(this);
    paint.beginNativePainting();

    glEnable(GL_LINE_SMOOTH);
    glEnable(GL_MULTISAMPLE);
    glClearColor(0.1, 0.96, 0.1, 1.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);


    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glVertexPointer(2, GL_DOUBLE, 0, 0);

    // draw my polygons:
    for(int i=0; i<100000; i+=5)
    {
        glDrawArrays(GL_POLYGON, i, 5);
    }
    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

    paint.endNativePainting();
}

void PaintWidget::updateTimer()
{
    paintEvent(nullptr);
}
```

This code simply renders 100000 polygons every 16ms.

And I'm not really satisfied with the prefomance of my code. It loads processor quite a lot (despite using of VBO). Can I make it more efficient, or this is the best perfomance?

Thanks.

Comment: You are using a single draw call per polygon. It is no wonder this is slow, and consuming all of your GPU load. And you are not using modern OpenGL at all - modern GL doesn't have `GL_POLYGON`, neither does it have `glEnableClientState` or `glVertexPointer`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well there's your problem:

> ```
> // draw my polygons:
> for(int i=0; i<100000; i+=5)
> {
>     glDrawArrays(GL_POLYGON, i, 5);
> }
> ```

You're doing 100000 draw calls for that single VBO. That's what taxing your CPU. For comparison the latest Doom on averages requires less than 1500 draw calls for a whole scene.

You should draw your whole geometry with a single call to `glDrawArrays` or `glDrawElements`. BTW: GL_POLYGON is no longer supported by modern OpenGL (the only supported primitive a GL_POINTS, GL_LINE* and GL_TRIANGLE*).

If your concern is about starting a new primitive, [with `glDrawElements` you can specify a special index that restarts](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Rendering#Primitive_Restart). Or (and that's actually the preferred method) just draw it as indexed triangles. Indexing is the key for efficient caching so if you want maximum performance that's the way to go.

Comment: Thank you, it really helped, but how should I index this VBO? I've already tryed few configurations, but they didn't work at all.

Comment: @Soup71: Create an element array buffer (`glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, …)`), fill it with an index array, and then `glDrawElements(…, NULL)`. You already have index creation code, and you can use a QGLBuffer and its `write` method for indices as well. Just keep in mind that vertex array objects only cover vertex *attributes*, so element index buffers must be bound and maintained separately.